# Make "home" from "motherhood"

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay

By removing seven letters from the word, "motherhood," the word, "home," can be formed. True or false?

Answer (score 3):

> True? If you remove seven letters from motherhood and arrange the rest, you are left with "dom", which is "home" in Polish, or alternatively "hem", which is "home" in Swedish.

Answer (score -4):

1. Removing 6 letters can do that.
2. I'm kinda new too, but no offense, but the Puzzling Stack Exchange usually has questions harder than this. Again, no offense intended, sorry if you felt this was mean.